# How to open a PdfADocument from an existing PdfDocument in itext7?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

In order to check uploaded PDF files for basic PDF/A conformance, I need to read them in as PdfADocuments.
But starting with version 7.1.6 this no longer works, but throws a PdfException(PdfException.PdfReaderHasBeenAlreadyUtilized)

```
class Controller
...
// get uploaded data into PdfDocument, which is passed
// on to different services.

InputStream filecontent = fileupload.getInputStream();
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes,0,bytes.length)) != -1) {
    filesize += read;
    buffer.write(bytes, 0, read);
}

ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray());
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input); 
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

AnalyzerService analyzer = new AnalyzerService();
if(analyzer.analyze(pdf)) {
    otherService.doSomethingWith(pdf);
}
...
```

---

```
class AnalyzerService
...
public boolean analyze(PdfDocument pdf) {
    PdfADocument pdfa = new PdfADocument(
        pdf.getReader(), pdf.getWriter() <-- PdfException here
    );
...
}
```

Up to and including iText 7.1.5 this worked.

With 7.1.6 I get "com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Given PdfReader instance has already been utilized. The PdfReader cannot be reused, please create a new instance."

It seems that I need to get the Bytes from the PdfDocument as a byte[], then create a new PdfReader from it. I have tried getting them from the pdf.getReader().getOutputStream().toByteArray(), but that doesn't work.

I'm quite lost at the moment on how to create that PdfADocument from the given PdfDocument.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach uses the same `PdfReader` and (even worse) the same `PdfWriter` for both a `PdfDocument` and a `PdfADocument` instance. As both can manipulate the `PdfReader` and write to the `PdfWriter`, that situation is likely to result in garbage in the writer, so you shall not do this.

Simply always consider a document with both a reader and a writer as work-in-progress, something one cannot treat as a finished document file, e.g. extract for intermediary checks.

As you want to *check uploaded PDF files*, why don't you simply forward the `byte[]` from `buffer.toByteArray()` to the `analyze` method to create a separate reader (and, if need be, a document) from? This indeed exactly would check the uploaded file...

Furthermore, if your input document may be PDF/A conform and is treated specially in that case, shouldn't you also manipulate it as a `PdfADocument` if it is? I.e. shouldn't you first check in your analyzer for conformance and in the positive case use a `PdfADocument` for it also in your controller class?

Comment: thx @mkl! The PdfWriter and its output are never used, it's just there because PdfADocument insists on having one ;-) I changed the entire application to treat PdfDocuments as temporary and only pass on data in byte[] througout the workflow. This is rather tedious, though, and recreating a PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray))) every time leads to a noticeable performance impact. Is there any other object type that would be better suited for being passed on through a workflow?

Comment: *"The PdfWriter and its output are never used"* - then why do you have it there at all? There is a `PdfDocument` constructor with only a reader, no writer... probably using that constructor would suffice in your case...

Comment: Correct. The only reason was that 
- I was passing the PdfDocument as a sort of persistent object through the workflow (which appears to be a bad idea ;-) 
- the PdfADocument constructor invoked somewhere in that workflow wanted it, and I thought it would not be good to have both PdfDocument and PdfADocument read from the same PdfReader, but use different PdfWriter instances.

Comment: But in the light of your post, the whole concept does not seem to align with what these objects were designed for, so I'll abandon that approach.

Comment: Still wondering though  if there is an approach for using a single object throughout a workflow that is more in line with the general iText design principles.

Answer (score 0):

```
        PdfDocument SourcePDF=null;
        PdfADocument DisPDF =null;
        try
        {
            PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(input-Path);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(output-Path, new WriterProperties().SetPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0));
            writer.SetSmartMode(true);
            SourcePDF = new PdfDocument(Reader);
            DisPDF = new PdfADocument(writer, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A,
                new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "https://www.color.org", "sRGB", new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.sRGB_CS_profiles)));
            DisPDF.InitializeOutlines();
            //Setting some required parameters
            DisPDF.SetTagged();
            DisPDF.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-EN"));
            DisPDF.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));


            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(DisPDF, true, true);
            merger.Merge(SourcePDF, 1, sorsePDF.GetNumberOfPages());
            SourcePDF.Close();
            DisPDF.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             throw;
         }
```